# Does the esri javascript api Identify Task Return a FeatureSet?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to get the results of an identify task using ArcGIS JS API 2.7 into a featureSet so I can utilize this sample http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=16528 that takes the results of a datagrid store and exports them to an excel file. I have it working where one feature is being exported, I just need to have all selected features export. Does an Identify Task produce a FeatureSet?

Thanks!

```
 function executeIdentifyTask(geom) {
  //clear the graphics layer 
  map.graphics.clear();

  identifyParams.geometry = geom;
  identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
  identifyTask.execute(identifyParams,function(response){

 var polygonSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DOT, new dojo.Color([151, 249,0,.80]), 3), new dojo.Color([151, 249, 0, 0.45]));
     var markerSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 20, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([0, 0, 0]), 1), new dojo.Color([25,50,225,0.3]));

     var controlItems = [];
     var surveyItems = [];

     dojo.forEach(response,function(result){

       var feature = result.feature;

       if (result.layerName =="surveys"){
    showSurveysNameGrid();
        feature.setSymbol(polygonSymbol);
        searchType="selSurvey";
    surveyItems.push(attributes);
              var attributes = feature.attributes;
    var csvTextSurv = "DOCUMENT_N;TOWNSHIP_RANGE;SECTION\n";  


    csvTextSurv += attributes["DOCUMENT_N"] + ";" +
                           attributes["TOWNSHIP_RANGE"] + ";" +
                           attributes["SECTION"] + "\n";

        document.getElementById("csvSurv").value = csvTextSurv; 
        map.graphics.add(feature);
   }else{
     showPointNameGrid();
    feature.setSymbol(markerSymbol);
    var attributes = feature.attributes;
    controlItems.push(feature.attributes); 
    searchType="selControl"; 
    var csvTextMons = "POINT_NAME;SECTION\n";  

    csvTextMons += attributes["POINT_NAME"] + ";" +
                           attributes["TOWNSHIP_RANGE"] + ";" +
                           attributes["SECTION"] + "\n";
   }

     document.getElementById("csvMons").value = csvTextMons; 
   //add selected feature to graphics layer       
       map.graphics.add(feature);
 });

     if(surveyItems.length >0){
     showSurveysNameGrid();
     var surveysStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:   {identifier:'DOCUMENT_N',items:surveyItems}});
        var grid = dijit.byId('grid5');
        grid.setStore(surveysStore);
     }
 if(controlItems.length >0){
    showPointNameGrid();
    var controlStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({data:{identifier:'POINT_NAME',items:controlItems}});
    var grid = dijit.byId('grid4');
        grid.setStore(controlStore);


 }              

 });
```

}

Comment: elaborate on what a featureset is?

Answer (score 1):

If by featureSet you are referring to the [geoJson spec](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-collection-objects) then the answer is no. The identify task returns an [identifyResult[]](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jsapi/identifyresult.htm). This contains some basic information about each result and a graphic representation of the geometry.

It looks like the script you are wanting to use wants CSV so where does a FeatureSet come into play?

Comment: Oops, I did not mean to end it there. I am not sure if the script I want to use needs a featureSet, I just can't figure out why I am only getting one result in my csv output, even though the datagrid displays all the results I select. It seems like it needs to loop through, but again I am not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: might it be since you are overriding the place you are storing it? ie document.getElementById("csvSurv").value = csvTextSurv; where csvTextSurv is always going to be the last item?

Comment: Good point. I am such a newbie, what would I use instead to keep this from happening?

Comment: += would append.